# Upgraded to Craft 3 and lost my Commerce Gateways

Tags: craft3, payment-methods, plugin-craftcommerce2

I upgraded to Craft 3 and I went to my payment gateways and I have the old ones in there with no details such as keys. And my only gateway options are Dummy and Manual. I know there were changes such as `.commerce` being deprecated in some instances, so was this another change that I missed?  Do I have to buy a plugin for Commerce or make my own now?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commerce 2 moved all payment gateways to plugins.  You can see the relevant bit in the docs here: https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v2/payment-gateways.html

There are currently seven 1st party plugins that add payment gateways and the two most popular, Stripe and PayPal are free.  You can see the table for the remaining in the above link.  All of these are currently in the Plugin Store. 3rd parties can additionally write plugins that work with other payment gateways.

Comment: Bleh. I have another question, coming from craft 2 to 3, I'm not sure how to verify my craft commerce? I'm assuming I don't have to buy it again but I can't find anything at all about it.

Comment: Nevermind, found this https://id.craftcms.com